# how to display error msg using create element in form validation?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a validation registration form. How to display the error of the input empty in a span at the bottom of the input?
I want this span to not already exist and be created to display the message.

`enter code here`

```
<form action="" name="reg-form" method="post">
    <div id="name-box" onblur="validateFullname()" class="form-holder">
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="enter name" id="name" class="form-control">

    </div>
```

i want create a span element and display message after input or append to  div.

Comment: you can make the span hidden initially and display the span when error is encountered. CSS class have to be defined.

Comment: Can you post what you have coded already so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will look something like this:

1. Identify where the "Error Message" span will appear. It needs to be inside another element, even if that element is the body. My example contains: `<div id="ErrMsg"></div>`
2. You need an event that triggers both the validation, and the creation of the error span. Usually, that event is a button press. So let's go with that in this example:

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    var tmpL = $('#login').val();
    var tmpP = $('#pword').val();
    if( tmpL=='' || tmpP=='' ){
      $('#ErrMsg').html('<span>Please fill-out all fields</span>');
    }else{
      alert('Logging in now');
    }
});

$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  if ( $('#ErrMsg span').length ) $('#ErrMsg span').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LoginDIV">
  <div id="LName">
    Login: <input id="login" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div id="LPass">
    Pword: <input id="pword" type="password" />
  </div>
  <div id="ErrMsg"></div>
  <div id="btnDIV"><button id="mybutt">Login</button></div>
</div>
```

---

Note: the `<script>` tag that references the jQuery library is all that you need in order to use jQuery. jQuery just makes javascript easier, more consistent, and less-typing-required.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use [JQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org). It's built-in methods don't technically use a span, as you specified, but you could easily tack on your own function to un-hide the custom span you create. Or, better yet, just style their error-message `<label>` in the way you prefer.

Here's an example using just JQuery Validation:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="commentForm">
    <div class="form-holder">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-holder col-12">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </form>

  <script>
    var validator = $("#commentForm").validate();
    validator.showErrors({
      "email": "Please enter a valid email address"
    });
  </script>
```

(The example leaves out the includes for JQuery and JQuery Validation.)